# Notification not working in FF Web Extension

Tags: javascript, notifications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a browser extension that I coded using WebEx to make it work in Chrome as well as FF/Edge, without porting. The following code works perfectly in Chrome.

```
toast = function(message, interval) {
    if (!(Notification || !("Notification" in window)))
        return;

    if (Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
        Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
            if (permission === 'granted') {
                var notification = new Notification('Extension', {
                    icon: chrome.extension.getURL('/img/128.png'), body: message });
                setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), interval);
            }
        });
    } else {
        var notification = new Notification('Extension', {
            icon: chrome.extension.getURL('/img/128.png'), body: message });
        setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), interval);
    }
}
```

I know the above is the latest supported code and not the deprecated one as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission

FireFox does request permission from me at all. Do anyone have any idea why? Could it be because I am testing it in developer mode and not published?

In debug mode, the browser executes this this line: `Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {`
and then exits normally, but I don't get asked for permission.

Comment: Did you check out [permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/Firefox_OS_apps/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/Manifest#permissions) in MDN? Maybe it's something about [desktop-notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/Firefox_OS_apps/App_permissions#desktop-notification)?

Comment: I had already given "notifications" permission in the manifest file

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an extension, you should use the webextensions notifications api:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications